# Lexical parser issue with RestKit

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios5, restkit

Lexical parser issue
'RestKit/RKSearchEngine.h' file not found

However i have set the header search paths to the following in both project & application.

"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../Headers"
"$(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20"
$(SOURCE_ROOT)/RestKit/Build

Comment: What version of RestKit are you using?

Answer (score 1):

First, I would suggest upgrading to RestKit 0.10.1. They've made a lot of improvements, one of the more minor ones being that you no longer need to import various RestKit files, you should just be able to import `<RestKit/RestKit.h>`.

If that's not an option for you then you might try looking through the RestKit project files to find the location of RKSearchEngine and importing that specific location. Before upgrading my RestKit version I remember having some long RestKit import paths for the JSONParser and one or two other files.